# Stored images in blob is acting strange when user clicks to go to last page ( PHP )

Tags: php, image, mysqli, blob

I'm storing in DB only profile and profile heading  images. [BLOB]

If i change my profile picture or my header picture its works fine, its storing in my DB.
The funny thing is that when i go back one page the last uploaded image appears again.
I recorded it [here in this video](https://www.useloom.com/share/fa0c6390efaf11e6890b11e7a578f83d)
Watch it so you will understand whats going on.
I want to know why this happens?

this are my codes.

```
function profile_pic(){

//uploads imgs

global $conn;

if(isset($_FILES['proImage']['tmp_name'])){
    $img = file_get_contents($_FILES['proImage']['tmp_name']);
    $imgName = addslashes($_FILES['proImage']['name']);
    $imgSize = getimagesize($_FILES['proImage']['tmp_name']);
    if ($imgSize == false){

        $_SESSION['empError'] = 'Error';
    }else{
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET ProfileImage=? , ProfileImageName=? WHERE email=?");

        $stmt->bind_param("sss",$img, $imgn, $em);
        $img=$img;
        $imgn=$imgName;

        $em =  escape_string($_SESSION['useremail']);

        $stmt->execute();
        $lastId=$stmt->insert_id;
        $_SESSION['empError']= "Updated.";

        //return $lastId;

    }
  }
}
```

display imgs

```
function display_pic(){
    global $conn;


    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $em);
    $em = $_SESSION['useremail'];
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $rows = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $url =$rows['ProfileImage']; //blob row


    $b64 = base64_encode($url);
    $uri = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $b64;

    echo '<img class="avatar border-white" src="' . $uri . '"  />';
}
```

Comment: Turn off you r browser cache, does it still happen

Comment: Back buttons don't tend to reload the page from the server, but rather show you a previous cached version of the page. In some cases it doesn't even trigger "onload".

Comment: BLOB does not use `s` it uses `b` RTM http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: .....wait for it/them ^

Comment: Note:when the it load last image, its also changes in the DB image name and picture.

Comment: here `$stmt->bind_param("bss",$img, $imgn, $em);` that should fix it for you. Now watch someone pop that in below *lol* I sure hope not.

Comment: change it to what I said then come back and tell us what's "now" going on or not. I seem to be doing all the legwork here, but have probably somebody pull the rug from under my feet, as it were; which isn't proper Stack etiquette, IMHO.

Comment: The easiest solution would be _not_ to store images in the database, to begin with. Put files on the file system (where they belong) and ordinary data in the database.

Comment: You'll need to basically start over with a new uploaded file in order to see the changes here and using what I told you almost 10 mins. ago @JamesAllan

Comment: changing to "b" broke the images, didnt work mate

Comment: check for errors then http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and make sure you're using the right setting for BLOB @JamesAllan there are a few https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html

Comment: If i store in file the users pictures,other users will see who's using this.

Comment: Im using mediumblob

Comment: How can they see who's using it? Surly you don't let people browse the files on the server? Just create a random filename when they upload an image and store the name in the database.